# MS Excel 2010 supressing 0 value

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have columns B  D  F  H  J
The line is then Totaled in N eg =SUM(B7,D7,F7,H7,J7,).  When there is no data in cells B D F H J the result is shown as 0.
What I'm trying to do is only show a total value when data is input in any of B D F H J in N.
Is this possible please?

Thanks

Comment: Use conditional formatting, q.v.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the formula:

```
=IF(OR(B7<>"",D7<>"",F7<>"",H7<>"",J7<>""),SUM(B7,D7,F7,H7,J7),"")
```

If one of the 5 cells has a value, the total is displayed.

Comment: That still shows the 0 value in N

Comment: @Dennis Change 0 in the formula to ""

Comment: Thanks Reddy - that worked!!

Comment: @Dennis If it answered your question, you can mark it as answered. [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)